# How to get URL of current page displayed?

Tags: php, loop, permalinks, urls

I want to add custom PHP code to ensure that whenever a page on my site loads in my browser, the URL of that page is echoed to the screen.  I can use `echo get_permalink()`, but that does not work on all pages.  Some pages (e.g. [my homepage](https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/)) display several posts, and if I use `get_permalink()` on these pages, the URL of the displayed page is not returned (I believe it returns the URL of the last post in the loop).  For these pages, how can I return the URL?

Can I attach `get_permalink()` to a particular hook that fires before the loop is executed?  Or can I somehow break out of the loop, or reset it once it is complete?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what you would want to do with this URL? Are you trying to create sharable URLs? Assemble custom URLs for links/actions?

Comment: @TomJNowell I would like to enqueue a particular JS script, but only on certain pages (in this case, those pages are the homepage of my site in various languages:  https://www.example.com/, https://www.example.com/fr/, https://www.example.com/es/, etc).  The JS file will server to add hyperlinks to several titles that appear only on the homepage.

Comment: why not just use `is_home()` or `is_page( 'fr' )` etc and only enqueue the script if it's true?

Comment: @TomJNowell Well now my code is `if ( home_url( $wp->request ) == home_url() ) {  wp_enqueue_script();}`  This appears to fire on every home page, regardless of language.  Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and company? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6768793/247696

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`get_permalink()` is only really useful for single pages and posts, and only works inside the loop.

The simplest way I've seen is this:

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request )
```

`$wp->request` includes the path part of the URL, eg. `/path/to/page` and `home_url()` outputs the URL in Settings > General, but you can append a path to it, so we're appending the request path to the home URL in this code.

Note that this probably won't work with Permalinks set to Plain, and will leave off query strings (the `?foo=bar` part of the URL).

To get the URL when permalinks are set to plain you can use `$wp->query_vars` instead, by passing it to `add_query_arg()`:

```
global $wp;
echo add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url() );
```

And you could combine these two methods to get the current URL, including the query string, regardless of permalink settings:

```
global $wp;
echo add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

Comment: If permalinks set to plain: `echo '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`.

Comment: @Jacob I tried that, but it seems to be returning the URL of my homepage only.  As you can see in the top left on this page (https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/properties/hs0540/), where I have inserted code to `echo home_url( $wp->request )`.  I have ensured to include `global $wp` as well.  Permalinks are not 'Plain,' but set to 'Post Name.'  I don't see any relevant PHP errors in the log either.  This particular page is part of my dev site, which is otherwise blocked off to visitors.  I'm not sure if that matters or not.  edit:  Actually, hold that thought--could be user error.  Stand by...

Comment: @Jacob edit 2:  OK your code does indeed work.  My issue was that I was including the code in functions.php 'naked,' i.e. not in any function that is attached to a hook.  So your code was returning the URL of the homepage, regardless of the page that was displayed in my browser.  Once I moved the code inside a function--a function attached to a WP hook (wp_enqueue_scripts), it did indeed return the URL of the displayed page.  Do you know the reason for that behavior?  Maybe I need to create a new question for that.

Comment: @cag8f If the code sits "naked" in functions.php then you are running it before all the properties of the $wp object have been set up.  When you wrap it in a function attached to an appropriate hook then you are delaying its execution until a suitable point in the Wordpress code run.

Comment: These methods are all awesome, and great ideas for working with WordPress. You might add `trailingslashit()` to them though, depending on your needs.

Comment: $wp->request is null for me

Comment: Please see cag8f’s second comment.

Comment: This works fine, but it does not account for the forward slash at the end of the URL. Consider `$post_permalink = home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );` instead.

Comment: Something to keep in mind as well, this could also be a CSS or JS file as well (or really any request to the server)

Comment: @MaxYudin please don't use $_SERVER as it is not enabled on some hostings.

Comment: Becareful when you use `$wp->query_vars` with the page that has custom URL created from `add_rewrite_rule()`, the normal WP query with custom query will be exposed. Example: **/mycustompage/subscribe?pagename=mycustompage&mycustom_subpage=subscribe**. While all of these, the URL appears in browser is just **/mycustompage/subscribe**.

Answer (score 30):

You may use the below code to get the whole current URL in WordPress:

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
```

This will show the full path, including query parameters.

Comment: Hi - if you have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/ you'll see that your code doesn't actually preserve existing query parameters.

Comment: To preserve query parameters you'd need to replace the empty `array()` with `$_GET`. ie:
`home_url(add_query_arg($_GET,$wp->request));`

Comment: It won’t work if WordPress is installed in subdirectory

Comment: @BradAdams the answer wasnt working for me until I saw your comment about the empty array. Thanks!

Comment: the Brad Adams comment code unfortuntaely doesn't add a trailing slash to the request so your perma would end like /foo instead of /foo/

Answer (score 21):

Why not just use?

```
get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
```

That is for single pages.

For category pages, use this:

```
get_category_link( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
```

Simple script to get the current URL of any page:

```
// get current URL 
$current_url = get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
if( is_category() ) $current_url = get_category_link( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
echo $current_url;
```

Comment: +1 all other answers are much to complicated, this is just the simplest solution

Comment: This is the easiest way. +1

Comment: doesn't work with blog categories on my site

Comment: Only works for single posts and pages though.

Comment: This does not include URL parameters.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, this code worked fine:

```
$current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

I hope it will help someone, I tried all answers but this one was helpful.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for subdirectory installs.
When the `home_url` is `s.b/hm` and `REQUEST_URI` is `/hm/current_url/` then the value becomes `https://s.b/hm/hm/current_url`. The install directory is repeated.

Answer (score 11):

The following code will give the current URL:

```
global $wp;
echo home_url($wp->request)
```

You can use the below code to get the full URL along with query parameters.

```
global $wp;  
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
```

This will show the full path, including query parameters. This will preserve query parameters if already in the URL.

Comment: This snippet skips `wp-admin/plugins.php` in my current URL, it's only the root path and query strings.

Comment: Close! The trailing slash was missing, and thus causes a quick redirect to add it when WP parses it out, which gets a small SEO ding, so I added it below. So far this creates the exact URL

`global $wp;`
`$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request . '/'));`

Comment: @ShaneMcCurdy I guess you could also use [`trailingslashit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/) (see Jake's comment [above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed#comment512373_274572))

Answer (score 4):

The solutions here are all good but were not consistent with both local and remote server environments. So I came up with a simpler neat solution that works better **regardless of the WordPress permalink settings**.

```php
function getCurrentUrl() {
    $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    return ($protocol) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

```php
$currentUrl = getCurrentUrl();
echo $currentUrl;
```

The output will include URL query parameters and slugs.

Answer (score 3):

```
function current_location()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
        ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
        $protocol = 'https://';
    } else {
        $protocol = 'http://';
    }
    return $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

echo current_location();
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why this code solves the question?

Comment: In my opinion the most flexible solution. It works on any WP page (even on wp-admin, wp-login.php, archive pages, etc). Just notice, that it does not include any URL params

Answer (score 3):

```
global $wp;
$wp->parse_request();
$current_url = home_url($wp->request);
```

Comment: Always try and include a bit of an explanation with your answer so the OP gets a better understanding of what's happening.  That way we all end up learning and the community grows.  :-)

Comment: Aye, eight years later I'm still baffled _how_ this works, and _where_ you should use it (naked? inside a hook? a filter? the loop?... we have no idea).

Comment: I like that firing wp::parse_request() works for catching endpoints in the URL. That's just neat.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improved way of example that mentioned previously. It works when pretty URLs are enabled however it discards if there is any query parameter like **/page-slug/?param=1** or URL is ugly at all.

Following example will work on both cases.

```
    $query_args = array();

    $query = wp_parse_url( $YOUR_URL );

    $permalink = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );

    if ( empty( $permalink ) ) {

        $query_args = $query['query'];

    }

    echo home_url( add_query_arg( $query_args , $wp->request ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`wp_guess_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_guess_url/) is what you need. Available since version 2.6.0.

Comment: This just guesses the base URL. On the frontend, you end up with a similar effect to `home_url()`.

Answer (score 1):

After so much research of a simple task, a mix of all answers above works for us:

```
function get_wp_current_url(){
    global $wp;
    if('' === get_option('permalink_structure')) return home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
        else return home_url(trailingslashit(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request)));
}
```

No missing slash at the end and so on. As the question id about output the current url, this doesnt care about security and stuff. However, hash like #comment at the end cant be found in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (short and clean solution that includes the query strings in the URL too):

```
$current_url = add_query_arg( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

The output URL will look like below

```
http://sometesturl.test/slug1/slug2?queryParam1=testing&queryParam2=123
```

The solution was taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/leereamsnyder/fac3b9ccb6b99ab14f36)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, however one thing I've noticed is no-one mentioned using `get_queried_object()`.

It's a global wp function that grabs whatever relates to the current url you're on. So for instance if you're on a page or post, it'll return a post object. If you're on an archive it will return a post type object.

WP also has a bunch of helper functions, like `get_post_type_archive_link` that you can give the objects post type field to and get back its link like so

```
get_post_type_archive_link(get_queried_object()->name);
```

The point is, you don't need to rely on some of the hackier answers above, and instead use the queried object to always get the correct url.

This will also work for multisite installs with no extra work, as by using wp's functions, you're always getting the correct url.

Comment: Hm. Possibly there _might_ just be the issue of _not_ having a universal way of specifying _all_ kinds of possible objects. In other words, things like `get_post_type_archive_link()` work great _if_ you know, in advance, that you _have_ an archive link. Thus, you'll still need to figure out _what kind_ of object you have before using a _specific_ helper function on it. As WP gets more and more object types, you need to have more code to deal with each individual case separately...

Comment: get_queried_object ALWAYS contains information that can be leveraged to ascertain what type of Wordpress object it is. This includes post archives. This is easy enough to test. Simply try viewing the results of the method call in each template type, and you will gain a better understanding of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

WP updated something and now the **property** request of the global **$wp** is empty by default. You must call the special method **[parse_request](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5ca2a817abb025a01bf9a8056ed00c766f7e6eed/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L133-L397)** before to get data of this property.

So it was this way:

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request );
```

Now it should be the next way:

```
global $wp;
$wp->parse_request();
echo home_url( $wp->request );
```

P.S. I'd like to leave in comments under the most popular response, but I don't permissions to leave comments.

Comment: But parse_request should already be called by $wp->main() at the bottom of that file.

Comment: Yeap, maybe, but probably some plugin broke it and my class stopped to work correct, because $wp->request just returned an empty string. So safely to use $wp->parse_request() to asure that $wp->request is correct.