# redirect_to how to make it simply work with get parameter or similar?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, redirect, login, wp-redirect

I want, as an exception, do a redirect if a user reaches a point where he needs to be logged in, to the login screen, and as soon as he logs in and certian conditions are fullfilled (a flag set as `myappname_allow_redirect`) I want to redirect back to the last url the user was at

In some shortcode that requires the user to be logged in:

```
try{

  $mus = new myappnameUserService();
}catch (myappnameNeedsLoginException $e){
  global $wp;
 //this is the easiest way supposedly to get the current URL see here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed
  $thisUrl = home_url($wp->request);
  $thisUrl =  urlencode($thisUrl);
  myappname_redirect_to_url('/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . $thisUrl . '&myappname_allow_redirect=1');
}
```

functions.php

```
    function myappname_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
    {

      if ($user instanceof WP_User) {
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
          //check for admins
          if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
          } else {
            //if something is set her for exceptions, we allow regular redirect as well
            if($_GET['myappname_allow_redirect']){
                return $redirect_to;
            }else{
//but normally we redirect to a standard url
                return 'somethingelse';
            }
          }
        } else {
          return $redirect_to;
        }
      }
      //is there a user to check?

    }

    add_filter('login_redirect', 'myappname_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```

first it seems to work, I get redirected to mydomain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=xxxx&myappname_allow_redirect=1

but

```
myappname_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
```

`$redirect_to` is empty, and so is `$request`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question as to why the variables are empty, but I've found the best way to redirect is to hook into the `template_redirect` filter and use `wp_redirect()` function directly.

Comment: @Peter the problem is I only want to trigger this after successful login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was...

`myappname_login_redirect` needs to return `$redirect_to` in any case

otherwise the redirect to gets lost

background:

wp-login.php will render the redirect_to value into an input hidden into the login form.

so arriving at

wp-login.php?redirect_to=www.example.com

will render

an

`<input type="hidden" value="www.example.com">`

this value will be empty, if the filter does not return it by default

so fix...

```
   function myappname_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
    {

      if ($user instanceof WP_User) {
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
          //check for admins
          if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
          } else {
            //if something is set her for exceptions, we allow regular redirect as well
            if($_GET['myappname_allow_redirect']){
                return $redirect_to;
            }else{
//but normally we redirect to a standard url
                return 'somethingelse';
            }
          }
        } else {
          return $redirect_to;
        }
      }
      //is there a user to check?

return $redirect_to;
    }

    add_filter('login_redirect', 'myappname_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```