# Detect what link user clicks and Redirect to a specific page for logged in users only

Tags: php, functions, wp-redirect

I have a link in my WP website [Account link](http:///account).
I would like this to work normally for logged out users.
However for Logged-in users i would like this link to take them to another page url.

I have tried:

```
 function my_logged_in_redirect_sub() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() &&($_GET['account'] )  
) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 15498 ) );//the redirect page id
    die;
}
}


 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect_sub' );
```

The $_GET['url'] doesn't work

**Question**: How can i target a specific URL with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL of current page displayed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 examples which you will need to modify slightly to get it working for your specific needs.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or ID here') && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
    exit;
   }
}
```

Put this in your child theme functions file, change the page ID or slug and the redirect url.

You could also use code like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

You can add the message directly to the page or if you want to display the message for all non logged in users, add it to the code.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: ok perfetct, the 1st example worked! (I had to remove the ! since i want this to work for Logged in users) What i was missing is that is_page('add page slug or ID here') is actually detecting the Link, i thought it was indicating the page the user is currently in. Thanks!

Comment: Glad, that it helped you.