# Get the current post/page URL with plain permalinks

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

I got it to work with this:

```
$url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
```

However, if the permalink is plain, all I'm getting is the homepage url (instead of the post url).

So what's the best way to get the current post or page address link?

Comment: You can either use `get_permalink()` or use jQuery if it's something dynamic activity you're looking for. 
`var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only (/path/example.html)` or 
`var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL (https://example.com/path/example.html)` or 
`var origin   = window.location.origin; // Returns base URL (https://example.com)`

Comment: @Vishwa was hoping for a php way : )

Comment: `get_permalink()` should work for you. if you get problems in homepage, you can check with `is_page(home)`. however, for your code to work properly, you'll need `global $wp;` before your code

Comment: Also try this `global $wp;  
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL of current page displayed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed)

Comment: Just write this code in your post/page.php file `global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request );`

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) doesn't work for you? I'm unclear why you are trying to construct it manually.

Comment: this doesn't work for homepage, for example: `http://localhost/m/` is giving me `http://localhost/m/2019/05/18/bodev/` I need the exact URL on the address bar to do a sensitive comparison.

Comment: What about leveraging the [$_SERVER variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) instead?

You should be able to replace `$wp->request` with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: +1 Normally `global $wp; if ($wp->request == 'myslug) { /** Do something */ }` or `if (is_home) { /** Do something */ }` should just be fine. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `get_permalink()` is only for use within the loop and gets the permalink for the current post in the loop. It does not work reliably outside the loop, and does not work for archives or any page that's not a single post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `get_permalink()`. That function is intended for use inside the loop, and only works for getting the link to posts. It will not work for taxonomy archives, date archives, search results, or the latest posts page.

Normally you can get the URL to the current page with `home_url()` combined with `$wp->request`:

```
global $wp;
echo home_url( $wp->request );
```

This is because `home_url()` gets your site URL from the database, while `$wp->request` holds the path for the current request, which will be the slug for pages, date for archives, etc.

The problem with plain permalinks is that they don't use the request path, because this requires the standard .htaccess setup. Instead WordPress uses the query string to determine what to load.

So what you need to do is get the current query vars and append *those* to the URL. Thankfully those are also available in `$wp`, specifically as `$wp->query_vars`. This is an array of vars and values, so you can pass it directly to `add_query_arg();`:

```
global $wp;
echo add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url() );
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeap, this should't work with plain format. and also just `get_permalink()` also not going to solved your issue here. To solved your issue you need to first correct Page/Post id and WordPress default doesn't offer us any function to do that. So you need to make one to grab the correct id. example

```
/**
 * Get correct page or post id
 *
 * @return int
 */
if ( !function_exists( 'get_the_real_ID' ) ) {
    function get_the_real_ID() {
      $post_id = 0;
      if (in_the_loop()) {
           $post_id = get_the_ID();
      } else {
        if ( is_front_page() && !is_home() ) {
            $frontpage_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
            $post_id = $frontpage_id;
        } elseif ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
            $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
            $post_id = $page_for_posts;
        } else {
            global $wp_query;
            $page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

            if ( is_page() || is_singular() ) {
                $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
            } else {
                $post_id = 0;
            }
        }
      }
      return $post_id;
    }
}
```

Now just use this ID to grab your page/post url like this.

```
$id = get_the_real_ID();
$current_url = (empty($id)) ? home_url() : get_permalink($id);
```

I'm not sure that this is the best or perfect solution for your case or not but it should at-least will be work as you expected. I assume that you might change the permalink format or want to grab the proper url whatever format used? and uppon that I share this method. try and let me know.