# What is the global $wp object used for?

Tags: globals

In the wordpress documentation for [Global Variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables), I did not find information about the **$wp** global variable.

I found a plugin which declares the global **$wp** variable as follows:

```
public function login_form(){
   global $wp;
   ...
}
```

But this variable is never used inside the declared function, so I wonder what is going on.

The entire function can be found [here](https://github.com/glowlogix/wp-frontend-profile/blob/master/inc/class-wpfep-login.php#L198) *(links to the exact line in the GitHub WordPress Frontend Profile plugin)*

Comment: It is a global instance of [`WP`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/) environment setup class and listed among the other global variables under the link you provided.

Comment: Use of the main `$wp` object in plugins and themes is ***extremely rare***, and is usually a bad sign of code quality. In the example you linked to, it isn't even used, the line could be deleted and it would make no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It contains the main instance of the [`WP`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/) class, which is primarily responsible for parsing the request URL and querying the appropriate posts, as well as sending headers and handling 404s. It can be used for things like [getting the current request URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed/274572#274572).

If it's declared in a function but not used, it's likely a mistake, or left over from a previous version of the function that did use it. You would need to ask the plugin developer why.