# how to get wordpress page url php code

Tags: php, themes

So am trying to get wordpress current page url in the header.
I tried below code but not working,
Please it urgent.
your can see my client current [music](https://i.morenaija.ng/) theme.

```
$current_url = home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved here:

[How to get URL of current page displayed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed)

```
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
```